# it can not work to declare global type by typescript

Tags: typescript

I try to declare a global type instead of each file imports. There are no syntax errors in vscode and can goto definition by ctrl-click, but it no work. I guess it's the ts-node problem, because tsc doesn't have this problem.

```
error message
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts(2,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Mode'.
```

```
// src/index.ts
const mode: Mode = 'development'
console.log(mode);

// typings/index.d.ts
type Mode = 'production' | 'development'

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "typings/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}

// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx ts-node ./src/index.ts"
  },
```

Comment: you should import type Mode to file index.ts .
import {Mode} from './index.d.ts'; (I could be wrong in some details :) )
and make Mode visible for other files:

export type Mode = 'production' | 'development'

Comment: My purpose is to omit the import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `--files` option

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx ts-node --files ./src/index.ts"
  },
```

`ts-node` does not load `files`, `include` and `exclude` from `tsconfig.json` on startup by default.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing

Answer (score 0):

I just change types file's path and it worked. It confused me.

before `typings/index.d.ts` after `// typings/<module_name>/index.d.ts`